# TensorFlow Error: ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501 while importing _pywrap_ tensorflow_internal in Python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, package

How i can solve this error while import TensorFlow in:

1. Python 3.8.4.
2. Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.
3. 2GB Ram.
4. Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz.
5. Intel(R) HD Graphics.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\te
nsorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501 while importing _pywrap_
tensorflow_internal

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Users\Abdo-Prgraming\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501 while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem,  my solution was to install tensorflow throught Anaconda virtual env.

Install Anaconda from their [official website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and create virtual enviroment
and open the Anaconda Prompt then...

```
conda create -n name_of_the_env
conda activate name_of_the_env
conda install tensorflow
```

Comment: It will be the tensorflow 2 by default